# MySQL query equivalent of "AND", whereas "IN" is "OR"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a query that selects every row of an associative table where the second column indicates different values that must all be matched with the first column's.

Example: I have column X and Y. I want to get the values of X where X is defined with every Y specified.

```
x    y
======
a    1
a    2
b    1
a    3
c    2
c    3
```

`SELECT DISTINCT x FROM table WHERE y AND (2, 3)`

This query of course isn't valid. I would expect to get `a` and `c` somehow.

As I'm also trying to learn MySQL queries better, I would appreciate if you could give an explanation of the logic behind your answer if you can provide one. Thanks! :)

Comment: Why can't you use `WHERE ... IN()`?

Comment: Your input set is ambiguous.  Assume an additional row (x='d', y=3) - is that returned by your query?

Comment: what he means is that he wants those values of `x` where _both_ 2 and 3 appear in `y`.

Comment: If anyone feels like editing this question for clarity, go ahead. I can't find the right formulation for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for. If you confirm it,I'll explain you the query.

```
select x
from table
where y in (2,3)
group by x
having count(distinct(y)) = 2
```

Comment: Perhaps this is what I need, but for some reason I get no result from my test table.

Comment: I've used your example to write you the query :(

Comment: Actually, I retract what I said, I have results for the exact same table. Just not for the real table I use. Let me try some more.

Comment: Had made a small mistake, works like a charm! Mind explaining now? :)

Comment: Ah ok. If you simply write "select x from t where y in (2,3) group by x" you would get x value even though the y value is only 2 or only 3. If you add the having clause with "count(distint(y)) = 2" it returns the number of different values. If you put it equals to 2 you're sure that both values you were looking for are present. Hope you have understood despite my poor english.