# PHP & MySQL: how to narrow down the tag search result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I narrow down my tag search result?

for instance,

table of `root_tags`

```
tag_id tag_name
1       A
2       B
```

table of `root_mm_tagged_pages`

```
tag_id  pg_id
1       10
1       20
2       10
```

I want to get the page with the `pg_id 10`

I tried with this query below but it returns empty:

```
SELECT *
FROM root_tags

LEFT JOIN root_mm_tagged_pages
ON root_mm_tagged_pages.tag_id = root_tags.tag_id

WHERE root_tags.tag_name = 'A'
AND root_tags.tag_name = 'B'

ORDER BY root_mm_tagged_pages.created_on DESC
```

**note:** I get the value of the `A` through `$_REQUEST` so it is always dynamic. but `B` is always fixed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: A single field cannot have two values at the same time.  I'm assuming you want it to be `OR` not `AND` in between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my answer that derived from Tommy's hint,

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT root_mm_tagged_pages.tag_id as Atag_id, root_mm_tagged_pages.pg_id as Apg_id, At.tag_name as Atag_name FROM root_mm_tagged_pages

LEFT JOIN root_tags as At ON At.tag_id = root_mm_tagged_pages.tag_id ) AS Aat JOIN

( SELECT root_mm_tagged_pages.tag_id as Btag_id, root_mm_tagged_pages.pg_id as Bpg_id,  Bt.tag_name as Btag_name FROM root_mm_tagged_pages

LEFT JOIN root_tags as Bt ON Bt.tag_id = root_mm_tagged_pages.tag_id ) AS Bbt on Aat.Apg_id = Bbt.Bpg_id WHERE Aat.Atag_name = 'A' AND Bbt.Btag_name = 'B'
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE root_tags.tag_name = 'A'
AND root_tags.tag_name = 'B'
```

Do you mean `OR root_tags.tag_name = 'B'`?

**EDIT** Nvm, but what about:

```
WHERE root_tags.tag_name IN ('A', 'B')
```

Comment: he wants "AND" search, that means A and B must co-exist.

Comment: I don't understand... mySQL will be testing each row and when it comes to `WHERE root_tags.tag_name = 'A'` it will evaluate to true or false and if it is true then it will go on and see `AND root_tags.tag_name = 'B'` which will then ALWAYS be false since it can't be two values

Comment: maybe I should not use `where`... tested your edited version but still get the same result...

Comment: Okay so you want it so that the page_id you return has the related tag_name B if and only if the same page_id exists which has the related tag_name A? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. `Okay so you want it so that the page_id you return has the related tag_name B if and only if the same page_id exists which has the related tag_name A? ` yes you are right.

Comment: @Connor, your edit version is synatx correct, but it will not return correct result, as judda said, a single field cannot have two values at the same time, so IN ('A', 'B') cannot find a record where a field contains both A and B :)

Comment: @Tommy Yeah I understand but then I was really confused when they started saying they must coexist. Let me try this with a subquery

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure how to do this =/

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *
FROM root_mm_tagged_pages

JOIN root_tags as At
ON At.tag_id = root_mm_tagged_pages.tag_id ) AS Aat JOIN

( SELECT *
FROM root_mm_tagged_pages

JOIN root_tags as Bt
ON Bt.tag_id = root_mm_tagged_pages.tag_id ) AS Bbt on Aat.pg_id = Bbt.pg_id
WHERE Aat.tag_name = 'A' AND Bbt.tag_name = 'B'

ORDER BY Aat.created_on DESC

This should be slow i think, perhaps wait for another soln :)

Comment: thanks. tested it but I get an error - `#1054 - Unknown column 'root_tags.tag_id' in 'on clause'`...

Comment: test it again, i have a typo before as i just copy and paste :)

Comment: thanks again. the edited version makes sense now! lol 
tested it and it return an empty result though... :(

Comment: thanks. sorry was off for bed. just woke up and tested the newer version and I have this error - `#1060 - Duplicate column name 'tag_id'` sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In a similar question I asked, "nick rulez" gave a quite satisfying answer:
[MySQL query equivalent of "AND", whereas "IN" is "OR"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244331/mysql-query-equivalent-of-and-whereas-in-is-or)

```
select x
from table
where y in (2,3)
group by x
having count(distinct(y)) = 2
```

In your case, it would be:

```
select pg_id
from root_mm_tagged_pages
where tag_id in ('A', 'B')
group by pg_id
having count(distinct(tag_id)) >= 2
```

This would return any result having at least the tags `'A'` and `'B'`.

However, if you're going for a more "general case" search algorithm, I think it could be improved as such:

```
select pg_id
from root_mm_tagged_pages
where tag_id in (/* any amount of tags */)
group by pg_id
having count(distinct(tag_id)) > 0
order by count(distinct(tag_id)) desc
```

Which would return every result with at least 1 matching tag, but with the ones with the most matching tags first.

Comment: thanks. tested both the suggested queries and they return empty result though...:(